# WPF ListBox turn off hover effect

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've found and tried many solutions on the internet which should allow me to disable the **hover effect** of my WPF ListBox but none of them seemed to work for me. This screenshot shows the hover effect I'd like to hide or get rid of:

[image: hover effect]

This is (a simplified version) of the XAML code I currently have:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}" Grid.Column="1" Width="800"  Height="100" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Transparent" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

However, it doesn't seem to work for me for a reason or another. Could my parent ListBox (the one in the background) or another control override it's child's style by any chance? (I already tried to override the parents style as well)

Comment: I just created a new wpf-application with just a listbox, and i don't have the hover-effect by default.

Comment: That's pretty confusing. I've tested it on Windows 8 (as seen in my screenshot) and on Windows 7, where the hover effect displays in an uglier blue... I'll try creating a new wpf-application with just a listbox in a minute to verify whether or not it makes a difference.

Comment: Yes you're right, the ListBox doesn't even have a hover effect by default. So I guess it's there because we've a global style set for all sub controls. Is there any way to override this style? I'm currently trying to get started with <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>

Comment: Post your default-style here. Maybe we can help you.

Comment: If you just want to simply show some list items on UI then better use ItemsControl

Comment: I assume you do not need to select the item when you say you do not want hover effect. If then replace your ListBox with ItemsControl

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Modify the default style of a ListBoxItem

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Just add a trigger

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
```

Comment: Why not `<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">` and instead of redefining the entire style just add on top of it?

Answer (score 2):

Getting rid of the blue devil?

If you have no need to click on your items the following will make it disappear, the highlighting on mouse hover:

```
<ListBox IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Glad that" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="they are over" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="the days of the blue devil" />
</ListBox>
```